# Резиновый сайт при разрешении 1200x1024

Tags: css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой надо указать процент, чтоб смотрелось нормально при разрешении 1200х1024 для резинового сайта?

Comment: Процент чего? Ширины, высоты, освещенности, спирта в крови?)

Comment: 960px ширины оптимально! Но изучив статистику Google Analytics начинаешь понимать что этот вопрос неактуален!

Comment: При резиновой верстке указывается ширина 100%, а высота не имеет значения, потому как ее все равно контент потянет.

П.С. вы не правильно выразились, а мы вас не поняли.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего Вам нужно свойство `min-width`, которое позволит не уменьшать размер контейнера.
А вот какой именно Вам нужен процент, да и минимальное значение ширины - зависит от того, как оформлен сайт, и чем Вы его хотите наполнять.
Например, "`width:60%; min-width:760px;`"...